# Display Taxonomy Description on edit-tags screen?

Tags: taxonomy, categories

[image: Taxonomy description]

I want to add some helpful text to the edit-tags screen describing the proper use of each of my custom taxonomies.

I see [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) that a description can be added to a custom taxonomy — not to a term, but to the taxonomy itself. That would be a perfect place to put my help text, and I have, but I don't see where that's rendered at all.

From the Codex:

> **description**
>   (string) (optional) Include a description of the taxonomy.
>     Default: ""

In my custom taxonomy function's $args array:

`$args = array(
  'description' => 'Some helpful text!'
  [other args...]
  );`

Is there a hook for edit-tags that I can use to display the taxonomy's description, or another solution (ACF maybe) for inserting help text here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for where you've circled can be found in `wp-admin/edit-tags.php:295`

You'll notice there's nothing there. No hooks, no filters. You're out of luck for tapping into that cleanly.

Luckily you can do a duct tape method to still add it with jQuery. You can dynamically put text where you've circled by doing something like:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', function(){
    global $wp_query;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->base == 'edit-tags' || $screen->base == 'term') {
        $mytax = get_taxonomy($screen->taxonomy);
        if (!empty($mytax->description)) {
            ?>
            <script>
            jQuery(window).load(function() {
                jQuery('.wrap h1').after("<p class='description'><?php echo $mytax->description ?></p>");
            });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
});
```

---

### UPDATE

As you pointed out @Slam, you can use the `_pre_add_form` and `_term_edit_form_top` hooks to show the into around the area you're after. To do that, you can cycle through all the taxonomies and dynamically run the actions like so:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function(){
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies(); 
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        add_action("{$taxonomy}_pre_add_form", 'my_plugin_tax_description');
        add_action("{$taxonomy}_term_edit_form_top", 'my_plugin_tax_description');
    }
});

function my_plugin_tax_description() {
    global $wp_query;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->base == 'edit-tags' || $screen->base == 'term') {
        $mytax = get_taxonomy($screen->taxonomy);
        if (!empty($mytax->description))
            echo "<p class='description'>{$mytax->description}</p>";
    }
}
```

Although `_pre_add_form` fires in the left column - not directly below the h1 title.

Comment: I'm don't full understand hooks yet, but what about [taxonomy_pre_add_form?](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_pre_add_form/)

Comment: you're absolutely right, I'm embarrassed I didn't see that. I've updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

To @David Sword comments: If you want use standard taxonomy description (in the labels) use this code:

```
function my_plugin_tax_description() {
    global $wp_query;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->base == 'edit-tags' || $screen->base == 'term') {
        $mytax = get_taxonomy($screen->taxonomy);
        if (!empty($mytax->labels->description))
            echo "<p class='description'>{$mytax->labels->description}</p>";
    }
}
```